# Importing excel data from multiple sheets

Tags: r, shiny

I have a excel file that contains 2 sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2).
Both the sheets contains same data (with same column names)
Sheet 1 - 10rows and 5 columns
Sheet 2 - 20rows and 5 columns

Now, I need to import these data so that the the output data should be have appended data

This code only reads data from Sheet1

```
asd <- as.data.table(read_excel("pre.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1"))
dim(asd)
[1] 10   5
```

Expected output (Both sheets combined)

```
asd <- as.data.table(read_excel("pre.xlsx", sheet = c("Sheet1", "Sheet2")))
dim(asd)
[1] 30   5
```

Comment: Did you try `read.xlsx(..., sheetIndex=1)` from `xlsx` library?

Comment: `readxl::read_excel` could read only one sheet. But you could do `lapply(c("Sheet1", "Sheet2"), function(x) read_excel("pre.xlsx", sheet = x)) |> dplyr::bind_rows()`

Comment: Ok thanks. What is ````dplyr::bind_rows()```` . Are you using pipe operator?

Comment: Looks like I was beaten to the punch but yeah, loop through them and then merge

`do.call(rbind, lapply(c("Sheet1", "Sheet2"), function(x) read_excel("pre.xlsx", sheet = x)))`

 -------------------------- --------------------------

`bind_rows` is the `tidyverse` version of `rbind` and will stack the dataframes on top of each other.       

`|>` is the new pipe in R that is native. `%>%` is still common and, again, is from the `tidyverse`

Comment: is ````|>```` an operator in R. Did not know this:)

Comment: So its ````do.call(rbind, lapply(c("Sheet1", "Sheet2"), function(x) read_excel("pre.xlsx", sheet = x))) %>% bind_rows()````

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(c("Sheet1", "Sheet2"), function(x) read_excel("pre.xlsx", sheet = x)))` should be all

Comment: ok..............